# Converting to lapply in R - for loop with appending tibble

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing, lapply, tibble

I am trying to parallelize this for loop by first converting the loop into lapply.

sent is a tibble with around 20,000,000 rows

The for loop uses an index i to go through each row in sent. If two conditions are met, the 31 rows (from i-15 to i+15) are sliced and appended to another tibble (either femaleWindow or maleWindow).

Do you have any tips on how to convert this to lapply/ parallelize the for loop to save time?

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(sent)))
{
    if(i>15){h=i-15} else{h=1}
    j=i+15
    cut <- slice(sent,i) 

    if (cut[1,5]=="yes")
    {
        window <- slice(sent, h:j)
        leadcut <- window %>% filter(leader=="yes")
        x = fleadcut[1,4] %>% replace_na(list(leader="none"))
        if(x =="yes")
        {
            femaleWindow <- bind_rows(femaleWindow, window)
        }  
    } else if (cut[1,5]=="no")
    {
        window <- slice(sent, h:j)
        leadcut <- window %>% filter(leader=="yes")
        x = leadcut[1,4] %>% replace_na(list(leader="none"))
        if(x =="yes")
        {
            maleWindow <- bind_rows(maleWindow, window)
        }  
    } else{print(i)}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You probably want to refactor this; growing object is really slow. [slider](https://davisvaughan.github.io/slider/) or [Rcpproll](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html) may be good places to start.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: FWIW, "I am trying to parallelize this for loop by first converting the loop into lapply" <= this is a good strategy; no need to worry about parallelization per se until you've got a working `lapply()` call.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a representable data sample.